# pass value of object created when document loads into a variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In `getInitialState` I return `value: "off"`.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    value: "off"
  }
}
```

After my component mounts I want to pass the value inside `value` into a variable. I have tried:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var value = this.state.value;
}
```

but that does not work and if I console log `var value` i get an undefined value. However when I log `this.state.value` i get off. What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: where you call console log?

Comment: It does work. But `value` lives and dies inside of `componentDidMount`. Lookup how scope works in JavaScript.

Comment: Seems works fine https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/28065/

Comment: `console.log(this.state.value);
    var value = this.state.value;
    console.log(value);`

Comment: I am doing that inside `componentDidMount` and it's returning undefined still

Comment: @ogk have you checked mу example? Could you provide mode code

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var value = this.getInitialState().value
}
```

Or create a property called `state` and set it a sub-property `value` and then in your `getInitialState` set it:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    this.state.value = "off";

    return {
      value: "off"
    }
}
```

With this, you can then access it with your function:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var value = this.state.value;
}
```