# Load fetch into a variable React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Learning JavaScript and React Native and I seem to not be understanding how to put a json response into a variable I can access. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873307/pass-value-of-object-created-when-document-loads-into-a-variable-in-react), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573547/fetch-react-native-unexpected-token), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724781/react-native-fetch-not-working) and also the Mozilla documentation and also [this](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/premounting_with_componentwillmount.html) and a lot more but still don't seem to grasp the concept or get it to work.

```
export default class AwesomeApp extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { questions: [] };
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.getQuestionsFromAPI().then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        questions: res
      });
    });

    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/trivia';

    async function getQuestionsFromAPI() {
      fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
      .then(function(json) {
        questions = json;
        //console.log(questions[0]);
        return questions;})
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  }

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.question}>
      { this.props.questions[0] }
    </Text>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
        <CheckBox
        label={ this.props.questions }
        checked={false}
        onChange={(checked) => console.log('I am checked', checked)}
        />
    </View>
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeApp', () => AwesomeApp);
```

I get the error "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.getQuestionsFromAPI()'). Looking at it in a browser, setting:
    var quests = getQuestionsFromAPI()
returns a promise

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

while

```
console.log(questions[0]);
```

returns an object which is what I want. What am I not understanding?

Comment: You're not returning the promise in getQuestionsFromAPI. Try adding `return` on the first line. Could you also re-indent your code, it's unclear what object the functions belong to.

Comment: Do you mean after the function is called? [`return fetch(url)...`], I get `undefined is not a function(evaluating 'this.getQuestionsFromAPI()')` in the android emulator but in the browser it returns `PromiseStatus: resolved` and a `PromiseValue: Array[4]`. My challenge is getting this into a variable to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in the code sample you sent above.

Firstly, if you indent your code properly you will notice that the function `getQuestionsFromAPI` is declared within `componentWillMount`. Meaning that when you refer to it using `this` it is not found.

Secondly, `getQuestionsFromAPI` does not return a promise. You should `return fetch(...)`.

Finally, you are trying to get the questions using `this.props.questions`, but you are assigning the questions in the state, so you should be using `this.state.questions` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using ES5 and getInitialState as I found that easier to understand but comparing your answer, they seem to achieve the same thing.